# How to detect mouse over certain GUILayout/EditorGUILayout element?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a custom EditorWindow. And I want to determine which element located in the current mouse position.

When I use `GUI` or `EditorGUI` - it's easy.  `GUI/EditorGUI`use `Rect` position, to place an element where it must be. And my code can be like this:

```
Rect button = new Rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
List<Rect> elements  = new List<Rect>();

void OnEnable() {
   // loop to initialize elements and add them to the list
}

void OnGUI() {        
   foreach (Rect element in elements) { 
        if (element.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition)) {
            // get element information
        }
    }
}
```

But `GUILayout`/`EditorGUILayout` place elements automatically, they have not `Rect` coordinates.

So, how do I determine an element in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect().

[Example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect.html)

You must get it after each of controls drawing to know control position/size.

Using example:

```
private void OnGUI()
{ 
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        var buttonResult = GUILayout.Button(string.Format("Button {0}", i));

        var rect = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();
        var pos = Event.current.mousePosition;

        if (rect.Contains(pos))
        {
            OnMouseOver(i);
        }

        if (buttonResult)
        {
            OnButtonClick(i);
        }

    }
    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}

private void OnButtonClick(int buttinIndex)
{
    Debug.LogFormat("OnButtonClick {0}", buttinIndex);
}

private void OnMouseOver(int buttinIndex)
{
    Debug.LogFormat("OnMouseOver {0}", buttinIndex);
}
```

Comment: yeah, I saw this method, but I don't understand what to do if EventType is MouseDown or MouseUp or MouseDrag etc, not just Repaint. The code from that examlpe won't work

Comment: Useful example added